# iPhone Jailbroken Issue with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, xcode8, xcode9

Need to check whether device is jailbroken using cordova. I tried the cordova-plugin-jailbreak-detection plugin, but still can open the same in JAILBROKEN Device. then i got .m files from https://github.com/Shmoopi/AntiPiracy. it was working fine till XCode 8. In XCode 9, getting "System keyword is unavailable" error

Any latest plugin/class files to check Jailbroken compatible for latest XCode ?

Answer (score 0):

`system` call is not available for ios, remove `+ (int)systemCheck` and it should work for you. Also in `+ (void)killApplication` method comment `system` call

The `isJailbroken` method performs various check and if the score is `>= 3` then it marks it as Jail broken. Now as the system call is not available then we can live without the score of `+ (int)systemCheck` and proceed without it.